# How can I filter a list of files to download those that don't already exist?

Tags: bash, download, grep, wget, cut

I have downloaded some files into a folder, but the download was interrupted and not all the files were downloaded.

I do not want to redownload the gigabytes-worth of files I already have; I now want to skip the files that are already downloaded and download those which are not.

I have list of clear text URLs which I used to download the files in the first place. I wish to simply remove the links of the already downloaded files.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried wget --nc?

> `-nc`, `--no-clobber`:              skip downloads that would download to 
>                                      existing files.

(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4944295/skip-download-if-files-exist-in-wget)